# CCNet email does not include MSBuild results

Tags: email, msbuild-task, ccnet-config

We're using CCNet  1.4.4.83 but when an MSBuild task fails, we don't get the MSBuild results (i.e. missing file or whatever reason the compile failed) in the **email** notification.

I **do** see the build failure on the CCNet website (dashboard).

I can see a file called **msbuild-results.xml** being created in the artifacts folder, so the msbuild task looks like it's configured correctly.

It seems that for some reason the results are not merged when the email notification is created but is when the dashboard is viewed.

The email task is in the publishers section and after the  tag.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue: There is a section in **ccservice.config** that must be modified. It comes standard with a few XSL transformation but does not include MSBuild one.

```
<xslFiles>
    <file name="xsl\header.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\compile.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\unittests.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\fit.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\modifications.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\fxcop-summary.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl"/>
</xslFiles>
```

I added in the line

**<file name="xsl\compile-msbuild.xsl"/>**

and the email notifications now include the build results.

Please note: There is another XSL file (msbuild.xsl) that you **don't** want to use here. It provides every single step of the build process (not just warnings and errors). That could create an email that's several MB in size.